# VBA autofilter on database from date in specific cell

Tags: excel, vba

i am looking a VBA code to filter on a date :
In Sheet1 in the cell N25 i have the start date and in Sheet2 i have the database.
I would like to filter the database with the start date from the Sheet1

Please see my code that not working

```
Sub test_3()

Dim Date_start As Date

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        Date_start = CDate(Range("N25"))

   
    End With

    With Worksheets("Sheet2")
        With .Range("A1:AH" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
            .AutoFilter Field:=13, Criteria1:="=" & Date_start
  
    
    End With
    End With


End Sub
```

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Which sheet is the active one? If "Sheet2", you should change `Date_start = CDate(Range("N25"))` in `Date_start = CDate(.Range("N25")). Otherwise, it will work on the active sheet and return from "N25" of the active sheet...

Comment: Then, your code misses a " _" to end the line: `...End(xlUp).Row) _` instead of `End(xlUp).Row)`. It may be a typo...

Comment: Glad I could help!